# Git merge other branch into another branch?

Tags: git

Is it possible to merge other branch into another branch?

For example, I'm in `branch1` and want to pull `remote/develop` into `develop` branch and then merge develop into current `branch1`.

What am I doing is `checkout develop`(maybe `stash` first), `pull`, `checkout branch1` and then `merge develop`.

Is it possible to do all these with switch to `develop` branch ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A slightly quicker option would be to (while on `branch1`):

```
git fetch
git merge remote/develop
```

This will get your `remote/develop` merged into `branch1`, however it should be noted that your local develop branch won't be updated.

Answer (score 33):

What you are doing is the right thing.

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout branch1
git merge develop
```

> This will merge the `develop` branch into `branch1`

I don't know if you are asking for a shorthand for these commands or what, but this is the sequence I always use.

Alternatively, from your current branch `branch1` do

```
 git pull origin develop
 git push
```

This will merge `develop` branch into your `branch1` and push to update upstream `branch1`

Answer (score 3):

A simple option would be to (while on `branch1`):

```
git fetch origin develop:develop
git merge develop
```

This will fetch `develop` from the remote `origin` and point your local `develop` branch to it, and then get your (now updated) local `develop` branch merged into `branch1`.

In case your local `develop` has diverged from the remote *and* you want to replace it with what's in the remote, then use `--force` to tell Git to override your local `develop`

```
git fetch origin develop:develop --force
git merge develop
```